# Ruby app with Sinatra, Unicorn, and Mongodb

Tags: ruby, mongodb, sinatra, unicorn

I've been tasked with building a simple app. I don't have any experience with Sinatra, Unicorn, or Mongo. I'm struggling with figuring out where to start. I have experience with Rails and I keep on trying to think about things in Rails-terms and it's not helping. Everything I've read seems to suggest that Unicorn should be used in conjunction with NGINX. What is the purpose of boot.rb? This is what config/boot.rb looks like right now:

```js
require 'sinatra'
require 'mongo'
require 'mongoid'

require './app'
```

here is config/unicorn.rb:

```js
worker_processes Integer(ENV["WEB_CONCURRENCY"] ||3)
timeout 15
preload_app true

before_fork do |server, worker|
  Signal.trap 'TERM' do
    puts 'Unicorn master intercepting TERM and sending myself QUIT instead'
    Process.kill 'QUIT', Process.pid
  end
end
after_fork do |server, worker|
  Singal.trap 'TERM' do
    puts 'Unicorn worker intercepting TERM and doing nothing.  Wait for master to send QUIT'
  end
end
```

## config/mongoid.yml

```js
development:
  clients:
    default:
      database: db-name
      hosts:
        - localhost:27017
```

this is what I created for a procfile:

web: bundle exec unicorn -p $PORT -c ./config/unicorn.rb

Any thoughts?

Comment: is something not working?

Comment: Nothing works. I have not been able to figure out how to run the app or even run the server locally. I don’t have access to my computer at the moment but can share the errors tomorrow. Bundle exec rackup config.ru always leads to an error saying boot.rb could be not be loaded. Do you have any ideas? How would you go about setting this up?

Comment: @maxpleaner I haven't been able to find an example online of a configuration of the boot.rb file and I don't understand it's purpose. I also can't figure out what command/s I need to get things started. `bundle exec rackup config.ru` leads to `bundler: failed to load command: rackup`

Comment: You need `rack` in your gemfile.

Comment: @maxpleaner adding rack to the gem file leads to the same error. When i run just `rackup config.ru` i get the following error:  `cannot load such file -- .../config/boot (LoadError)` .